AS5600 encoder is not reading on Raspberry Pi 4
I'm trying to read the stepper motor angle using the AS5600 magnetic position encoder.
I'm using Raspberry Pi 4 and the pinout is the following:
VCC to 3.3V , GND to Ground ,SDA to GPIO2 (Pin 3) , SCL to GPIO3 (Pin 5) , DIR to Ground
The code I'm using is this:
import smbus
import time


bus = smbus.SMBus(1) # Define I2C bus number and AS5600 device address
AS5600_ADDRESS = 0x36


AS5600_REG_ANGLE = 0x0E  # Read-only register for angle value

def read_angle():
    # Read 14-bit angle value from AS5600
    data = bus.read_i2c_block_data(AS5600_ADDRESS, AS5600_REG_ANGLE, 2)
    angle = (data[0] << 8) | data[1]
    return angle

try:
    while True:
        # Read angle value from AS5600
        angle = read_angle()
        print("Angle:", angle)
        time.sleep(0.1)  # Wait for 100 ms before next reading

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Program stopped by user")


I tried replacing the encoder module and wires, but no use. I don't know what to do at this point, any suggestions?

please add a link to the AS5600 datasheet ... add it into your question... do not write a comment

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You did not mention what specific problem you're facing. You can use this library instead if your current code is not working.  https://github.com/Matthias-Wandel/AS5600-Raspberry-Pi-Python   Once your code is fixed, you can make a breakout board like this too: https://www.pcbway.com/project/shareproject/AS5600_Encoder_Board_edbb75cc.html

Update your code to read from the correct angle registers.
import smbus
import time

bus = smbus.SMBus(1)  # Define I2C bus number and AS5600 device address
AS5600_ADDRESS = 0x36

AS5600_REG_ANGLE_H = 0x0C  # High byte of angle value
AS5600_REG_ANGLE_L = 0x0D  # Low byte of angle value

def read_angle():
    # Read 14-bit angle value from AS5600
    data = bus.read_i2c_block_data(AS5600_ADDRESS, AS5600_REG_ANGLE_H, 2)
    angle = ((data[0] & 0x0F) << 8) | data[1]
    return angle

try:
    while True:
        # Read angle value from AS5600
        angle = read_angle()
        print("Angle:", angle)
        time.sleep(0.1)  # Wait for 100 ms before next reading

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Program stopped by user")


The high byte (0x0C) contains the 4 MSBs, and the low byte (0x0D) contains the 8 LSBs. You need to mask the high byte to get the correct 14-bit value. If you are also thinking about making an AS5600 encoder board of yourself, you can consider the following design:
https://www.pcbway.com/project/shareproject/AS5600_Encoder_Board_edbb75cc.html

BTW see also https://github.com/Matthias-Wandel/AS5600-Raspberry-Pi-Python
